# Finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, eigenvector

I'm having trouble finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors using command null in MATLAB. My lecturer didn't want us to use `eig`. Instead she asked us to find them using nullspace, but when I run my command, the output is an empty matrix.
This is the code:

```
A = 'C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\testproject.jpg';
B = imread(A,'jpg');
C = rgb2gray(B);
imshow(C);
D = im2double(C);
F = transpose(D);
G = F*D;
H = poly(G);
R = roots(H);
M = null(R)
```

The objective of this code is to find the SVD, hence find the singular values and the matrices U and V.

Comment: Laila, in your example, could R be a vector? In this case, the null command will return an empty matrix. You must find vectors orthogonal to R in a different way.

Comment: @AntonioL. I think it is.then,how can I find it?because me and my teammate starting to freak out because we cannot find any suitable command

Comment: Maybe if you copy the vector, so you make a nxn matrix, the comman 'null' might work. Regards.